# Python 3.x multiprocess TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am testing python multiprocess. I use pymongo to manage queue, my code and error is like below. I can't solve the issue and I don't know the root cause, please help me, thank you very much. I know multithreading could work, everything else works too, I had a test line saying:
process_crawler(seed_url, scrape_callback=scrape_callback, cache=cache, max_threads=max_threads, timeout=10)

```
import time
import threading
from mongo_queue import MongoQueue
from downloader import Downloader
import multiprocessing


SLEEP_TIME = 1

def threaded_crawler(seed_url, delay=5, cache=None, scrape_callback=None, user_agent='wswp', proxies=None, num_retries=1, max_threads=10, timeout=60):
    """Crawl a website in multiple threads"""
    # url queues to be crawled
    crawl_queue = MongoQueue()
    crawl_queue.clear()
    crawl_queue.push(seed_url)
    downloader = Downloader(delay=delay, user_agent=user_agent, proxies=proxies, num_retries=num_retries, cache=cache, timeout=timeout)

    def process_queue():
        while True:
            try:
                url = crawl_queue.pop()
            except KeyError:
                #crawl queue is empty
                break
            else:
                html = downloader(url)
                if scrape_callback:
                    try:
                        links = scrape_callback(url, html) or []
                    except Exception as e:
                        print('Error in call back for %s, %s' % (url, e))
                    else:
                        for link in links:
                            crawl_queue.push(link)

    threads = []
    while threads or crawl_queue:
        # the craw is still active
        for thread in threads:
            if not thread.is_alive():
                threads.remove(thread)
        while len(threads) < max_threads and crawl_queue.peek():
            # can start some more threads
            thread = threading.Thread(target=process_queue)
            thread.setDaemon(True)
            thread.start()
            threads.append(thread)
        time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)


def process_crawler(args, **kwargs):
    num_cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    print('Starting Multiprocessing.... CPU Number is ', num_cpus)
    processes = []
    for i in range(num_cpus):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=threaded_crawler, args=[args], kwargs=kwargs)
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    for p in processes:
        p.join()



Traceback (most recent call last):
Starting Multiprocessing.... CPU Number is  8
  File "C:/Users/Michael Qian/Desktop/Python/MyScraper/process_test.py", line 15, in <module>
    test(1)
  File "C:/Users/Michael Qian/Desktop/Python/MyScraper/process_test.py", line 10, in test
    process_crawler(scrape_callback.seed_url, scrape_callback=scrape_callback, cache=cache, max_threads=max_threads, timeout=10)
  File "C:\Users\Michael Qian\Desktop\Python\MyScraper\process_crawler.py", line 58, in process_crawler
    p.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 212, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 313, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 66, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 59, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 106, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in _main
    self = pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried the multiprocessing and ran into the very same problem. The problem was caused by sharing the `MongoClient` object between the processes.

Have a look at [FAQ: Using PyMongo with Multiprocessing](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#using-pymongo-with-multiprocessing)